# Crystal Report problem in database Logon using c# winform, Mysql as Database, and ODBC

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, odbc

I have encounter this problem [Error in Actual runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVX70.png) and to be honest i have search and discover many ways to solve a similar problem. But my system problem always occur.

One of the solution i found on youtube is to have this on my app.config
but when i add it nothing change.

I really need help for this guys.

this message always persist and when i enter the correct info it says error wrong credentials.

Comment: Use a connection string with username and password : https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/

Comment: i have that too using ODBC.

Comment: Can you access the database with MySQL tools?

Comment: yes, i can access it through ODBC. and also using connection class i made.